# "there is no cask support for Catalina . . . please build from Homebrew formula"

Tags: homebrew-cask

I get

```bash
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
Error: Because of the limitation of build system, there is no cask support for Catalina(10.15) and earlier, please build from Homebrew formula.
```

from the command `brew upgrade`. How should I proceed?

If I understand correctly (which I'm not sure I do), some of the packages I have installed do not support cask any longer.  If so, I would identify those packages, remove them, and install the corresponding formulae (if available), but I don't know which packages are causing this error.

**Edit:** `brew doctor` doesn't say anything about the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Googling brought me to your post, as well as [this line in railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/blob/2db483db12e7fdd4aa4f95311365090434bfb3dc/Casks/emacs-mac-spacemacs-icon.rb#L6). `brew tap` included it in the list.

`brew untap railwaycat/emacsmacport`

fixed it for me. I hope it does for you!

I made a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/issues/309) for the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, that didn't work for me: the `brew untap` command itself causes the same error and subsequent `brew rm` commands, `brew update` commands, and `brew upgrade` commands give the same error, too. But, your answer suggests a promising direction of investigation.